# I need an image lightbox for a server-side rendered Nuxt.js app

Tags: nuxt.js, lightbox

I am building my first JAM stack site using contentful and nuxt.js with a static pages deployment on netlify. Do you have any suggestions for implementing a simple lightbox for image galleries? I tried several Vue solutions -     vue-cool-lightbox, vue-easy-lightbox, vue-image-lightbox but I haven't been able to make them play nice with nuxt which is completely server side rendered (mode static).

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem. For nuxtjs I was only able to find this. I will continue to work on this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GZbl.jpg)

[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-light-gallery)

Comment: It's not clear how this answers the question. Can you add some details to describe how to interpret the links you provide? Perhaps pull out the code of interest and provide it in your answer.

Comment: Did you edit your answer or were the changes in the target of one of the links? If you edited your answer, it's not showing up here yet. If you didn't, it would be good to include the pertinent pieces of the code inline in your answer, or at least provide a little more context regarding what to look for when you follow the links.